# how to check if the edit box is empty or not in VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I was creating vs++ code using MFC framework .I have a Cedit Box named "IDC_EDIT1" in the form.Can anybody tell me how to check if the edit box is empty or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WM_GETTEXTLENGTH message:

```
int length = SendMessage(hwnd,WM_GETTEXTLENGTH,0,0);
if(length == 0)
{
     MessageBox(0,"The edit box is empty.",0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CEdit *editBox = (CEdit *) GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);

if(editBox == NULL)
  return;
CString str;
editBox->GetWindowTextW(str);

if(str.IsEmpty())
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a calculator programme and I was checking on button press whether edit box control is empty or not.

The `IDC_Display`(Edit control) is connected to variable `m_Display`(`cEdit` Type)

I took another variable `cString` Type (`m_TrialString`). declare this on class definition just below `m_Display`.

on Button click event you write:

```
void CNewCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()

{   
m_Display.GetWindowText(m_TrialString);
if (m_TrialString.IsEmpty())
    AfxMessageBox(_T("The CString is EMPTY"),MB_OK);
else
    AfxMessageBox(_T("The CString is NOT EMPTY"), MB_OK);
```

}